# Juniper SSG5 find bandwidth eater

Tags: bandwidth, juniper, ssg5

I looking for a way to get the list of the top bandwidth eater on my Juniper ssg5. On my old OpenBSD Box I had a command line version of ntop. It was just perfect.

How can I do the same thing whith the SSG?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you get to set up a port mirror on the switch the SSG is connected to and from there you can sniff, ntop, tcpdump, wireshark, or nfsen as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Junipers session analyzer. You can find it at: https://tools.juniper.net/fsa/
You're suppose to make a session dump first and load it then into the analyzer. Instructions can be found here: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB8690

Answer (score -1):

configuring j-flow might be able to help to you.

http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/erx/junose90/swconfig-ip-services/html/ip-jflow-stats-config.html

Comment: J-Flow isn't available on devices running ScreenOS: http://kb.juniper.net/index?page=content&id=KB12911

Comment: Also, if you've got bandwidth problems, enabling *flow can further destroy network performance.

Comment: so , what your saying is ScreenOS is a piece of **** ?

Comment: Nope, just your response. :) And your mastery of your/you're. 

But seriously, few companies will port the latest technology back to all former products. Port mirroring is probably the best option for the lower end SSG; if you expect to need JunOS functionality you should be getting a newer box (or a SSG-520M/550M).